# Change component size in system composer

Tags: matlab

How can I change a component size in MATLAB system composer by means of APIs (command line or MATLAB code) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use system composer native API:

```
archModel= systemcomposer.loadModel('archName');
archComp2Resize= lookup(archModel, Path='archName/archComp')
archComp2Resize.Position = [300 600 100 170]
```

going over the code:
line 1> loads the model into memory
line 2> creates an object out of the target component
line 3> edits the position, the array has this strucutre [bottomleft topleft bottomright topright].

For more system composer programmatic API visit this page here: https://www.mathworks.com/help/systemcomposer/referencelist.html

Note that this question is a duplicate on Matlab answers. Here: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1923270-change-component-size-in-system-composer?s_tid=srchtitle